# Ajax call on spring controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, servlets, controller

I have an issue that I would like to solve.

First in my spring application I want to use a defined mapping.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Every time I used and ".html" link my controller has been call.

Here my problem : 
When I want to use an ajax call, he can't find any defined controller and it is normal because only .html are mapping.
My ajax call look like : /website/search/{var} :
{var} is defined, client side.
Like you can see I didn't put an .html extension at the end and I don't want to.

How can I make it work.

Btw : When I use "/" it's working.

But I think it's better to have a particular extention in url-pattern

regards,

Comment: can you post your ajax code snippet

Comment: function (var, process){
   return $.get('nav/search' + var, function(item) {
       return process(item);
})